# boost::property_tree::json_parser::read_json cannot read files if path contains cyrillic characters

Tags: c++, boost, boost-propertytree

Is it possible to open files that have cyrillic parts in their path? I am able to read/write cyrillic *contents* of files, but I do not know how to open the file as

```
json_parser::read_json
```

only has std::string as a parameter and no std::wstring. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a limitation inherited from the C++ standard streams. Microsoft's streams have a non-standard extension to accept `wstring` paths, but PTree doesn't allow them.

Try using Boost.Filesystem's streams. Open the stream outside the function and pass the open stream to `read_json`.